# How to determine next level using a formula?

Tags: php, equation

Thank you for any help you can provide on this.

If we have:

```
$level = floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 4 * ($c_xp + 500) / 100 * 2)) / 2) - 1; //GET LEVEL
```

For instance if:

```
$c_xp = 1200
```

Then:

```
$level = 4
```

Then I am asking if:

```
$level = 4
```

How much xp to get to level 5?

How can I get the amount of xp required to achieve the next level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula to get the minimum XP required to reach a level $level is given by:

```
$minXP = 12.5 * (pow((2 * $level + 3), 2) - 41);
```

So you can set $level = 5 and $level = 4 and find the difference between them.

Comment: In php there is no "power" operator, `^` is a bitwise (XOR) operator. Use [pow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) instead. For bigger exponents use [bcpow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php), +1 for the formula !

Answer (score 1):

### Analyse:

I ran a script to view the XP needed for each level:

```
$current_level = 0;
for($c_xp = 1;$c_xp < 7000;$c_xp++){
    $level = floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 4 * ($c_xp + 500) / 100 * 2)) / 2) - 1; //GET LEVEL
    if($level > $current_level){
        $current_level++;
        echo "c_xp $c_xp level $level<br>";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
c_xp 1 level 1
c_xp 100 level 2
c_xp 500 level 3
c_xp 1000 level 4
c_xp 1600 level 5
c_xp 2300 level 6
c_xp 3100 level 7
c_xp 4000 level 8
c_xp 5000 level 9
c_xp 6100 level 10
```

We can see that level 1 is an exception, then the difference of XP from level 2 to level 3 is 400, from level 3 to level 4: 500 and level 4 to level 5: 600 and so on...
The pattern is now clear,

**Level 1** -> 1 XP

**Level 2** -> Start a 100 XP

**Level 3** -> Increase by 400 (500 XP)

**Level 4** -> Increase by (400 + 100) 1000XP

**Level 5 to Level X** -> Keep increasing by 100

---

### The code:

With the above analyse, I could come up with a loop in a function:

```
$c_xp = 1200;
$level = floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 4 * ($c_xp + 500) / 100 * 2)) / 2) - 1;

echo 'Next level: '.current_level_xp($level+1).'<br>';
echo 'XP needed for next Level: '. (current_level_xp($level+1) - $c_xp);

function current_level_xp($current_level){
    if($current_level <= 1){
        return(1);
    }else{
        $increase = 400;
        $needed = 100;
        for($i=0;$i<$current_level-2;$i++){
            $needed += $increase;
            $increase += 100;
        }
        return $needed;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Next level: 1600
XP needed for next Level: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a math / formular plotting tool of your choosing to get an idea of the results of the used equation (which presumably isn't yours):

[image]

Now, there's probably even a way to reverse your formula for translating `y` into `x`. But I'm unsure if there's a `floor` reverse.

Comment: Just occured to me it's kinda redundant, for the inversion anyway. `x = ((10*y+15)^2-1025)/2`